# Minified angular2 - Has anyone done this successfully yet?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, minify

I'm building an angular2 app, and started working on my build/minification process.  I can successfully build and run my application in a dev mode, with individual JS files, which are unminified.  But when I build them into a single, concatenated file my application will not run.  All I get is a **blank page, no errors on the console.**  I've tried webpack, gulp, etc, all have the same result when running in the browser.

I'm curious if anybody has gotten this to work yet? Or has any suggestions?

One thing I notice in my compiled JS (from typescript) is that the bootstrap call is present, but never executed if I set a break point.

I'm compiling my TypeScript to es5 and System modules.  **Angular2.beta12**

Index.html

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/ncss.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/App.css">
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="libs/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2/bundles/router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2/bundles/http.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->


    <!--<script src="app/app.min.js"></script>-->

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>

        System.import('app/app.min.js')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));

    </script>

</head>


<!-- 3. Display the application -->


<body>
    <app-component></app-component>

</body>
```

TSConfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/app",
    "outFile": "./dist/app/app.min.js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "dist/libs"
  ]
}
```

Comment: There are known issues with minification https://github.com/angular/angular/search?q=minified&state=open&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: I think I have my answer.  I was cherry-picking the files I needed when I built my ```dist``` directory.  I ended up copying the entire angular2 and rxjs directories to make all files available to systemjs, then it started working.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have my answer. I was cherry-picking the files I needed when I built my `dist` directory. I ended up copying the entire `angular2` and `rxjs` directories to make all files available to SystemJS, then it started working. Thanks all!